# Do ingresses in Kubernetes create pods?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm confused as to how Kubernetes Ingresses work. My conceptualization of it is that they're a Kubernetes service of type "loadbalancer" which also runs a Pod that works as a reverse proxy, redirecting requests to different services on the cluster. The reverse proxy Pod is based off of some ingress controller implementation, like nginx or HAProxy.

Is this actually how ingresses work though? On the Kubernetes cluster I'm working with, I don't see any pods managed by the ingresses on it - are ingresses really running a pod/group of pods behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is "sort of" correct.

An ingress resource in itself **does not create any pods**. It is more of a "routing table" where you say "for host X and path Y, route traffic to service Z"

You separately install an ingress **controller** services, such as [ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx), and this is what actually creates the loadbalancer.

Traffic comes into the cluster on the loadbalancer created by the ingress controller, and the controller then uses the routing table you created (the ingress resource) to determine where to route the traffic.

You can have more than one ingress controller in your cluster and each one can handle traffic, so in your ingress resource, you can indicate via either the `ingress.class` annotation (although this is deprecated, I believe) or by using the `ingressClassName` directive in the ingress resource.

More reading is available [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-class)